# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'customer

Tags: python, django

```
class RequestProcess(dxmodels.WorkflowEnabled):

    def __init__(self):
        lang = self.customer.user.customerprofile.language

    @xworkflows.on_enter_state('documents')
    def on_documents(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update_timestamps()
        ctx = {'request': self}
        EmailFromTemplate('request-required-documents', extra_context=ctx, lang=lang)\
            .send_to(self.customer.user)

    @xworkflows.on_enter_state('validation')
    def on_validation(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.update_timestamps()
        validate_requirements_for_request(self)

    @xworkflows.on_enter_state('signature')
    def on_signature(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.customer_product.lock()
        self.contract = create_contract(self)
        self.update_timestamps()
        ctx = {'request': self}
        EmailFromTemplate('product-request-accepted', extra_context=ctx, lang=lang)\
            .send_to(self.customer.user)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Now I know the problem is there :

```
def create_request_from_external(obj):
    ...
    req = Request(**{
        'state': 'documents',
        'request_type': get_request_type(obj.customer),
        'customer': obj.customer,
        'created_by': get_system_user(),
        'entered_documents_at': datetime.datetime.now(),
    })

    req.save()
    obj.request = req
    obj.save()

    create_customer_product(req, obj.product)

    audit.log('system',
              verb='created',
              target=obj.customer.user,
              action_object=req,
              message=_('Customer created for %s') % obj)

    # Build initial requirements state
    validate_requirements_for_request(req)
    return req
```

because

```
class Request(RequestProcess, FolderLinkMixin, TimeStampedModel):
```

I have the following error `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'customerd`. I don't want to put `lang = self.customer.user.customerprofile.language` in each method. I just want to instantiate once a variable. What could I do to fix it? Do I need to fix that directly in the class `Request` or in `RequestProcess`

For instance, if I write a method, remove the `__init__` method and comment the other methods, it works fine.

```
@xworkflows.on_enter_state('deposit')
def on_deposit(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.update_timestamps()
    self.customer_product.lock()
    create_loan_from_request(self)
    ctx = {'request': self, 'deposit_date': self.loan.product.deposit_date}
    EmailFromTemplate('deposit-notice', extra_context=ctx, lang=self.customer.user.customerprofile.language)\
        .send_to(self.customer.user)
```

### Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/24-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/24-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 359, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/24-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 294, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/24-django/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 345, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/24-django/loanwolf/core/management/commands/gen_fake_data.py", line 583, in handle
    options=options)
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/24-django/loanwolf/core/management/commands/gen_fake_data.py", line 244, in create_operation
    req = app.accept()
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/24-django/loanwolf/requests/models.py", line 625, in accept
    return create_request_from_external(self)
  File "/home/jeremie/Projects/Work_Projects/24-django/loanwolf/requests/utils.py", line 123, in create_request_from_external
    'entered_documents_at': datetime.datetime.now(),
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'customer'
```

Comment: What's the signature of `Request.__init__`?

Comment: There is no explicit `__init__()` method in Request, it gives me `<unbound method Request.__init__>` in the interactive shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have replaced the model's `__init__` method with one that does not accept *any* arguments:

```
class RequestProcess(dxmodels.WorkflowEnabled):

    def __init__(self):
        lang = self.customer.user.customerprofile.language
```

Note also that `lang` is only available in the `__init__` method, you cannot access it anywhere else because you did not set `self.lang`.

I would avoid overriding the `__init__` method for models wherever possible. In this case, I think it would be better to define a property instead.

```
class RequestProcess(dxmodels.WorkflowEnabled):

    @property
    def lang(self):
        return self.customer.user.customerprofile.language
```

Inside your model methods, you can then access `self.lang`.

Comment: It works, but why can't we just override the `__init__` method?

Comment: You could just override the `__init__` method, but I recommended against it because it often leads to bugs in my experience. If you did, you would have to accept `*args` and `**kwargs` and call `super()`.